# kotlin - How to extract/convert a String from TextInputEditText?

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I just want to get two `.text` from a TextInputEditText and convert them into a String.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin)
        val email = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginEmail).text
        val password = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginPassword).text

        val test = email.plus(password)

        button.setOnClickListener {
            //Toast.makeText(this,password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            println(test)
        }

    }
}
```

The Toast there works just fine, but I can't do any operation with the return from $email nor $password, they don't seem to be of the type String.

What types are they and how can I convert them to String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.buttonLogin)

    button.setOnClickListener {
        val email = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginEmail).text.toString()
        val password = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginPassword).text.toString()

        //Toast.makeText(this,password, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

        val test = email.plus(password)

        println("Button Pressed")
        println(test)
    }

}
```

}

Fetching the data must happen inside the setOnClickListener, then everything is working correctly.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it explained what was wrong with the code in the question, and what to change (rather than just dumping more code and leaving the reader to identify and analyse the differences).

Comment: I guess you didnt see what was written underneath the code:
"Fetching the data must happen inside the setOnClickListener, then everything is working correctly."

Answer (score 0):

EditText.text are not String, they are Editable. You need to call .toString() to convert them into string.

Comment: How exactly, for this example?

val email = findViewById<TextInputEditText>(R.id.loginEmail).text